# Is Antlr the right tool to trace Java method calls with parameter names and values, and return result?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, trace

I want to print out Java method calls with names and values of parameters, and return results.

I don't want to manually add the trace statements, especially when the code is in a 3rd party library. I need to understand the interactions with the library, especially when callbacks are used.

I have tried to use a wrapper, but ran into problems, so subclassing is better. (i.e. either wrappedObject.methodA() or super.methodA() calls)

It's a pain to write this code especially when there are lots of methods.

I wish Java can do this automatically, since it has everything to make this possible easily.

What is the best way to do this? Substituting objects with the wrapper or subclass is a compromise.

So, the next step is to add the tracing code to the wrapper or subclass. I thought of writing a parser to generate the code.

I have used yacc & lex before, and just found out about Antlr.

Is Antlr the right tool to do this? How would I do it please? I haven't used Antlr before, but have seen it around.

Thanks.

Here's what I want to do -

```
// 3rdParty library under investigation, with evolving versions
import com.3rdParty.lib.Service;
import com.3rdParty.lib.Callback;

MyExistingClass {

    Service service = new Service();

    // Need to understand 3rd party library service and callback interactions
    // Also need to write my own callbacks using 3rd party interface

    if (traceMethod1) {
      service.doSomething(param1, new CallbackWrapper(), param3);
    }
    else if (traceMethod2) {
      service.doSomething(param1, new CallbackSubclass(), param3);
    }
    else {
      // Original code
      // Service calls Callback methods
      service.doSomething(param1, new Callback(), param3);
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 3rd Party code - Service calls Callback methods

package com.3rdParty.lib;

public Callback extends SomeBaseClass {

    public void methodA(int code, String action, SomeClass data) {
        // do method A stuff
    }

    public String methodB(String name, boolean flag) {
        // do method B stuff
        return result;
    }

    ...etc.
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Wrapper class - traceMethod1

package com.my.package;

import com.3rdParty.lib.Callback;

public CallbackWrapper implements SomeCallbackInterface {

    Callback cb = new Callback();

    public void methodA(int code, String action, SomeClass data) {
        logger.debug("CallbackWrapper.methodA() called");
        logger.debug("  code = " + code);
        logger.debug("  action = " + action);
        logger.debug("  data = " + data);

        cb.methodA(code, action, data);

        logger.debug("CallbackWrapper.methodA() returns");
    }

    public String methodB(String name, boolean flag) {
        logger.debug("CallbackWrapper.methodB() called");
        logger.debug("  name = " + name);
        logger.debug("  flag = " + flag);

        String result = cb.methodB(name, flag);

        logger.debug("CallbackWrapper.methodB() returns result = " + result);

        return result;
    }

    ...etc.
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Subclass - traceMethod2

package com.my.package;

import com.3rdParty.lib.Callback;

public CallbackSubclass extends Callback {

    public void methodA(int code, String action, SomeClass data) {
        logger.debug("CallbackSubclass.methodA() called");
        logger.debug("  code = " + code);
        logger.debug("  action = " + action);
        logger.debug("  data = " + data);

        super.methodA(code, action, data);

        logger.debug("CallbackSubclass.methodA() returns");
    }

    public String methodB(String name, boolean flag) {
        logger.debug("CallbackSubclass.methodB() called");
        logger.debug("  name = " + name);
        logger.debug("  flag = " + flag);

        String result = super.methodB(name, flag);

        logger.debug("CallbackSubclass.methodB() returns result = " + result);

        return result;
    }

    ...etc.
}
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but this sounds more like a job for aspect-oriented programming (for example use [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) or [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/)) than something that you'd need a parser for.

Comment: Thanks. Just edited original post with example code to illustrate question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this sort of thing in Java is to work with byte code rather than source code.  Using BCEL (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) or ASM (http://asm.ow2.org/), you can dynamically create and load modified versions of existing classes, or even entirely new classes generated from scratch.

This is still not easy, but it's much easier than trying to do source code translation.

For your particular problem of tracing method calls, you can make a custom ClassLoader that automatically instruments every method in every class it loads with custom tracing code.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR is not the right tool.  While you can get Java grammars for ANTLR that will build ASTs, ANTLR won't help you, much, trying to modify the ASTs or regenerate compilable source text.

What you need is a [Program Transformation System (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).   These are tools that parse source code, build ASTs, provide  you with means to modify these ASTs generally with source to source transformations, and can regenerate compilable source text from the modified tree.

The source-to-source transformations for a PTS are usually written in terms of the language-to-be-transformed syntax (in this case, java):

```
      if you see *this*, replace it by *that* if some *condition*
```

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit is such a PTS with an available Java front end.

What you want to do is very much like instrumenting code; just modify the victim methods to make them do your desired tracing.  See [Branch Coverage Made Easy](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf) for examples of how we implemented an instrumentation tool for Java using such source-to-source rewrites.

Alternatively, you could write rules that replicated the victim classes and methods as subclasses with the  tracing wired in as you have suggested.   The instrumentation is probably easier than copying everything. [Of course, when you are writing transformation rules, you really don't care how much code changes since in your case you are going to throw it away after you are done with it; you care how much effort it is to write the rules]

See [DMS Rewrite Rules](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html) for a a detailed discussion of what such rules really look like, and worked example of rewrite rules that make changes to source code.

Others suggest doing transformation on the compiled byte code.  Yes, that works for the same reason that a PTS system works, but you get to do the code hacking by hand and the transforms, written as a pile of procedural goo operating on JVM instructions are not readable by mere humans. In the absence of an alternative, I understand people take this approach.  My main point is there *are* alternatives.